# How to print directly in a HTML page using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, printing

I'm developing a billing software. Can print a receipt but again click print button in print page then only printing

For Ex:

1. I'm clicking print button in HTML page,
2. next automatically open google chrome print window.
3. and again click print button,

Now printing, I want to be print directly. How to remove 2nd and 3rd step via programmatic.

How to rectify this problem anyone help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printpage()
    {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

I'm using above code this is output is redirected to google chrome print page.

And Again click print button then only printing,

1. I want to be print directly
2. For example am click print button in HTML page means automatically printing.
3. Cannot ask any inputs.
4. And cannot display any other dialog boxes.

Anyone help me please.

Comment: This is impossible, for good reason. Otherwise, random web pages would force your printer to print ads all the time. Also, DON'T SHOUT AT US. Typing in all caps is considered rude.

Comment: k, can edited, Am using thermal printer to print bill, Cannot cut paper for every page via PHP, How to cut paper every page end.

Comment: Certain printers come with an API to interface with the printer. I have done something similar with networked label printers and asp.net. You will need to see what API, if any, your printer provides. Be aware though it is the server that ends up doing the printing **not** the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining

1. am click print button in HTML page: Yes you will have to click on print button to request the browser to perform an action
2. next automatically open google chrome print window: Of course, it will be opened as printer/page settings will be asked even in ms word same thing happens while printing it asks for preferred printer & page
3. and again click print button: Finally you will be asked to submit your confirmation

Understand the whole process & please being on SO don't make a wish

Answer (score 0):

you need to develop desktop based application that connect your web to your computer..
so your web cant request directly to your desktop program instead via browser...
you can use java applets to do that...